# Distributing a Java console program

Tags: java, netbeans

I have created  a Java console application using Netbeans.  In the Netbeans dist directory I have the class file of the project.  Now I need to give the executable files to someone else
who will run them on another PC.

Which file I should send? How can he run them on his PC?  Is there any way to create an exe type file?

Both PCs have the JDK installed.

Answer (score 3):

Build a [jar file with a main class](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html) specified in it.

If he has Java installed and .jar is associated with that, he should be able to just double-click on it.

Alternatively from a command line he'd be able to run:

```
java -jar program.jar
```

There *are* programs around to create executable wrappers around this, but a jar file is a simpler solution in terms of packaging - it's worth trying that to start with.

Answer (score 0):

In additon to Jons answer:

If you have a runnable jar to start with, it is frequently much easier to package it up in an EXE file.  If you have the need search Stackoverflow for JSmooth and one-jar.

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans actually answers your question. If I do a Clean/Build, the output says:

To run this application from the command line without Ant, try:
java -jar "insert_your_project_name_here.jar"

Answer (score 0):

theres a handy page about this here:

[java tools tutorial](http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~parrt/course/601/lectures/java.tools.html)

It describes creating jar files a little further down the page

Answer (score 0):

You can go to run menu and select clean and build project or shift+f11 after this go to dist folder in project folder and use .jar file and run that by hint say in over .